# Norm in algebraic number fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Consider an algebraic number field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and its ring of integers $O$. If we take any element $\xi \in O$ and we want to calculate its norm $N_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}}(\xi)$, is the norm the constant term of its minimal polynomial?

I know that in general the norm is the constant term of characteristic polynomial. But at least sometimes it seems to be true that it is the constant term of minimal polynomial. So is it true when the element belongs in the ring of integers? If not how do I know when the norm is the constant term of minimal polynomial? ${}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a quadratic number field, $N(2) = 4$. However, the minimal polynomial of $2$ is $x-2$.

Comment: When do I know if its the constant term of the minimal polynomial or not? Because minimal polynomials are easier to form usually than characteristic polynomials.

Comment: The minimal polynomial usually *is* the characteristic polynomial. (incidentally, you have the sign wrong on the norm, if the number field has odd degree)

Comment: Yeah I know that you have to change the sign when the degree is odd.

Comment: So is it true that minimal polynomial = characteristic polynomial if $deg(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)) = deg(\mathbb{Q}(\xi))$?

Comment: @Kplusn: Yes, for a simple reason: the minimal polynomial is a factor of the characteristic polynomial. So if the degrees are equal....

Comment: Thanks. This makes my life so much easier..

Answer (score 3):

The constant term of the minimal polynomial of $\xi$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ equals $N_{\mathbb{Q}(\xi)/\mathbb{Q}}(\xi)$. So the answer to your first question is yes if $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) = \mathbb{Q}(\xi)$. On the other hand we have $N_{E/\mathbb{Q}}(\xi) = (N_{\mathbb{Q}(\xi)/\mathbb{Q}}(\xi))^{|E:\mathbb{Q}(\xi)|}$ for any extension field $E$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\xi$.

Comment: Thanks, the last sentence is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's not if and only if; e.g. consider $\xi = 1$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: You are right, thanks.